# How to add a random strings from a 2d array to a 1d array [C++]

Tags: c++, arrays, string, random

So, I have a 1d character array `char boo[1024]`.

And I have a 2d array, lets say `char* names[] = {"apple", "orange", "grape"}`.

The user will input a string of unknown size into `boo`.

I have to declare a 3rd array `char pot[1024]` and its contents have to be:

**boo** + '**M**' + a random word from **names** + '**N**' + random numbers of size 4 digits.

I am new to C++, and I cant really understand how to do this..

Hope someone can help me out with a small code snippet on how to do the above task in C++

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using character arrays in C++, use vectors and strings. This isn't C.

Comment: What happened if boo has exactly 1024 characters!  you need more memory allocation for pot.

Comment: Yes pot size of pot should be more than boo..

Comment: Can you please explain the sentence "boo + 'M' + a random word from names + 'N' + random numbers of size 4 digits"? Like, what is `N`???

Comment: The question could be improved by showing the code you had before you asked the question. As it is, you've demonstrated no effort at solving your own problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you try this:

```
char boo[1024] = "For example Hello";
const unsigned int name_size = 5; // For example 5, you can your needed size
string names[name_size]; // You need to add items to names
string pot(boo);
pot = pot + "M" + names[rand() % name_size] + "N" + to_string(rand() % 9000 + 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks!! :D got my desired results!! :)

Comment: @418 Great :). When you accept an answer flag it as "accepted answer". I offer you try `vector` form `<vector>` library. For more information follow this [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/).

Comment: Yes i am trying out <vector> library now.. sorry i forgot to flag accepted answer.. ^^ Im new on this site..

Comment: @418 Very good! One point about [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com): Put your code segments in ``. In the previous comment change <vector> to `<vector>`